# Help with jQuery Traversal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom, jquery-ui-sortable, traversal

I'm struggling a bit with traversing in jQuery. Here's the relevant markup:

```
<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
    <li>
        <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Vza76tCxL._SL160_.jpg">
        <div class="controls">
            <span class="move">✜</span>
            <span class="delete">✘</span>
        </div>
        <div class="data">
            <h1>War and Peace (Oxford World's Classics)</h1>
            <textarea>Published to coincide with the centenary of Tolstoy's death, here is an exciting new edition of one of the great literary works of world literature.</textarea>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51boZxm2seL._SL160_.jpg">
        <div class="controls">
            <span class="move">✜</span>
            <span class="delete">✘</span>
        </div>
        <div class="data">
            <h1>A Christmas Carol and Other Christmas Writings (Penguin Classics)</h1>
            <span>Optionally, write your own description in the box below.</span>
            <textarea>Dicken's Christmas writings-in a new, sumptuous, and delightful clothbound edition.</textarea>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is code for a jQuery UI 'Sortable' element. Here's what I want to happen.

When the Delete thing is clicked (`$('.delete')`), I want the `<li>` item it's contained within to be removed.

I've tried using `$('.delete').parent().parent().remove();` but in the case of having two items, that seems to delete both of them. I'm a bit confused by this. I also tried using `closest()` to find the closest `li`, but that didn't seem to work either.

How should I best traverse the DOM in this case?

Thanks!

Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
   $(this).parentsUntil('li').parent().remove();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/

Note: available in jQuery 1.4+

Answer (score 1):

The [`.closest('li')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) should work to get the `<li>`.

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

It will return the first `<li>` element that is an ancestor of your link.

An alternative is [`.parents('li:first')`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('li:first').remove();
});
```

You can omit the [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) if you don't have nested lists.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using a class selector in your 'remove' line.. that means every element with the class `.delete` is being affected, thus why multiple elements are being deleted.

Try this instead:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

The `$(this)` object is the element that was actually clicked on, so while the click function applies to ALL `.delete` elements, the line inside only applys to the current one.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to try to make a reduction of your selector:

```
$('li').has(this)
```

Comment: Traversing up to the `<li>` from the element will be quicker.

Comment: Yes, that seems logical reasoning indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to give the `<li>`s id's so you can do something like `$('#myLI').remove();`

Comment: That wouldn't be very convenient when getting the `<li>` relative to the `.delete` that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a class to the li items and use closest(), so it would be something like $('.delete').closest('.lirow').remove() where the li items had a class of lirow.